# How to control the volume of the audio in separate apps iOS?

Tags: ios, audio

In my app I have some voice feedback that is vocalized from time to time. Whenever user is listening to Spotify or Pandora for example, especially, trance/electronic kind of music my voice feedback from the app is not that distinct and loud enough.

Can I somehow control the volume of my apps audio and the volume of the apps that are running in parallel or it's controlled by iOS only?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: See the information on **audio ducking** here -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html